# Android Studio - jar/aar file location in the gradle dependency cache?

Tags: android, caching, android-studio, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

Folder names of the gradle dependency cache containing jar/aar libraries seem to be ciphered .
 Is there a method or tool or studio menu that allows us to get those .jar and .aar files?
 (I know I won't need to manipulate them as long as we stay in Studio). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to search *.jar or *.aar in the cache folder. The library file names are not ciphered.